# Можно ли вернуть в редактор VB кода в 2015 студии списки процедур

Tags: visual-studio-2015

В более ранних версиях студий в верхней части редактора кода формы были два выпадающих списка, где быстро можно было найти нужный метод в коде формы. Можно ли его как то вернуть? Может где в настройках есть....

Comment: Tools > Options > Text Editor > Basic > General > Navigation Bar. Оно?

Comment: Супер! Оно! Спасибо! Оформляйте в виде ответа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tools > Options > Text Editor > Basic > General > Navigation Bar.